# Meteor / Blaze: updating list properties with minimal redraw

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I'm encountering serious performance issues related to Blaze redraw. I know that my data structure is at fault but I can't find a way to fix it. This is a bit of a long one: I'll do my best to lay it out clearly.

**The goal / the problem**
I want to create a schedule view where users can schedule tests. Users should be able to drag and drop test slots, but the resulting redraw is so slow that the thing is unworkable.

**The data**
I have a `Sittings` collection which stores details about testing times. Each sitting has a list of `scheduleGroups` (i.e. exam1 and exam2 happen on Tuesday, exam3 and exam4 happen on Wednesday) The structure looks more or less like this:

```
var sitting = {
  "_id" : "sittingId",
  "name" : "Amazing Sitting",
  "locationIds" : [
    "room1_id",
    "room2_id"
  ],
  "startDate" : ISODate("2015-07-01T04:00:00Z"),
  "endDate" : ISODate("2015-07-02T04:00:00Z"),
  "scheduleGroups" : [
    {
        "_id" : "dEb3mC7H8RukAgPG3",
        "name" : "New group",
        "booths" : [
            {
                "boothNumber" : 1,
                "slots" : [
                    {
                        "examId" : "exam1",
                        "dayNumber" : 1,
                        "startTime" : {
                            "hour" : 8,
                            "minutes" : 0
                        },
                        "endTime" : {
                            "hour" : 9,
                            "minutes" : 30
                        },
                        "candidateId" : "odubbD42kHDcR8Egc",
                        "examinerIds" : [
                            "GQmvyXbcmMckeNKmB",
                            "GfoBy4BeQHFYNyowG"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
        "locationId" : "room1_id"
    }],
  "examIds" : [
      "exam1",
      "exam2",
      "exam3"
  ]
```

};

**The HTML**
Sitting is defined as global context in `Router.current().data` hook. This is part of the redraw problem. Anyway, the following HTML produces the following layout (img below).

```
<template name='scheduler'>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='tabpanel'>
        <div class='tab-content' id='scheduler-content'>
            {{#each getScheduleGroups}}
            <div class='container-fluid schedule-wrapper'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='scheduler-inner-box placeholder-box'></div>
                    {{#each booths}}
                    <div class='group-column-head scheduler-inner-box'>{{boothNumber}}</div>
                    {{/each}}
                </div>
                <!-- Sittings can take place over several days, normally 2 days -->
                {{#each sittingDays}}
                <div class='day-wrapper'>
                    <h3 class='text-center'>Day {{this}}</h3>

                    <!-- This helper returns a list of start times: [June 1 9AM, June 1 915AM....] -->
                    {{#each getScheduleTimes ..}}
                    <div class='row time-row'>
                        <div class='group-row-head scheduler-inner-box'>
                            <span class='box-content'>{{this}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Loop through each booth, so that each slot has a square for that boot
                            i.e. June 1 9AM has space for booth 1, and booth 2, and booth 3, etc
                         -->
                        {{#each ../../booths}}
                        <!-- Paper starting now tells us if there is a slot scheduled to begin at this time or wher its empty-->
                        <div  class='scheduler-inner-box {{#unless paperStartingNow ../.. ..}}open-booth{{/unless}}'>
                            {{#with paperStartingNow ../.. .. boothNumber}}
                            <!--
                                getSlotStyle calculates height and colour, depending on how long the paper is and whether
                                it's ready to go: i.e. does it have a candidate and the right number of examiners?
                            -->
                                <div  class='paper-tile tile' {{getSlotStyle this ../boothNumber 'paper'}}>
                                    <span class='slot-name'>{{getSlotName}}</span>
                                </div>
                                {{#if slotHasCandidate}}
                                <div class='candidate-tile tile' {{getSlotStyle this ../boothNumber 'candidate'}}>
                                    <span class='slot-name candidate-name'>{{getCandidateDisplay}}</span>
                                </div>
                                {{/if}}
                                    {{#each slotExaminers}}
                                    <div class='examiner-tile tile' {{getSlotStyle .. ../../boothNumber 'examiner' index}}>
                                        <span class='slot-name examiner-name'>{{profile.name}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    {{/each}}
                            {{/with}}
                        </div>
                        {{/each}}
                    </div>
                    {{/each}}
                </div>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Rendered layout]

**The Issue**
When a user drops a slot (purple tile) onto an empty space, or drags a candidate or examiner to another tile, I update the collection and let Meteor redraw. However the whole thing redraws and I can't find a way to isolate.

Here's the code for moving a whole slot, candidates examiners and all.

```
moveSlot: function (originalBoothNumber, originalSlot, dropBoothNumber, newSlot) {
    check( originalBoothNumber, Number );
    check( originalSlot, Object );
    check( dropBoothNumber, Number );
    check( newSlot, Object );

    //pull the old slot
    var originalBooth = _.findWhere( this.booths, {boothNumber: originalBoothNumber} );
    originalBooth.slots = _.without( originalBooth.slots, originalSlot );

    //insert the new one
    var dropBooth = _.findWhere( this.booths, {boothNumber: dropBoothNumber} );
    dropBooth.slots.push( newSlot );

    var modifier = {
        $set: {}
    };

    modifier["$set"]["scheduleGroups." + this.getIndex() + ".booths"] = this.booths;
    return Sittings.update({_id: this.getSitting()._id }, modifier);
},
```

**Do I need to change the way I store `Sitting.booths`?** If anyone can recommend a better data structure that will trigger a redraw of just the slot, I'd really appreciate it. I've found a hack that puts every slot into a session variable but there's got to be another way.

Thanks for your patience and your help,
db

Comment: Would you consider using react front-end? ReactJS was built specifically to do isolated renders. It is a bit of a ramp up though.

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess that the whole thing redraws and it's rather intensive because you're only using a single template. Try breaking it up into sub-templates and see if that helps.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack Just tried sub templates but that doesn't solve it, for the reason @jwalll points out in his answer. Even changing `moveSlot` to push and pull specific slots doesn't do it. `booths` is invalidated either way and the grid redraws. Will try `reactiveVar` approach now and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

It's because you store the whole set of `slots` inside one document of `booth`. Once you update a `slot`, the whole document is consider updated.

**Solutions**

IMHO, I don't think you need to change the structure, *unless* you have build a feature to search for `slot` or `booth`. You can set it up by create a series of `reactiveVariable` or a `reactiveDictionary`, your template should depends only on that reactive variable. Every time you updated, consider to sync between two of them, either manually or automatically.

**PS.** I'm not doing any affiliate with this site: https://www.sportsplus.me. But if you sign up -> home -> mlb -> anycontest -> click on plus, you can see their masterpiece infinite scroll with partly redraw. (Open your dev-console and watch the changes in element). They do exactly the same thing you're trying to do with minimum redraw.

Comment: Looks like `ReactiveVar` was the way to go. A pain to set up for this structure, but it basically works. Thanks @jwall, @CaptSaltyJack and @k.chao.0424 for your solutions.